# Set an Independent taskbar icon in WPF

Tags: wpf

I want to set my taskbar icon that should be independent of the application icon, that should not affect the other icons used in the application.

Tried with the other existing solution in stackoverflow, none of them works.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered such a problem. It showed differently. You can not finish. The system reads the icon (for the panel and for the application the same icon) the size of one icon (32x32, 48x48, 128x128, 24x24).You can make something a custom decision in the title, change the content and so on. But I do not think that this is a good decision.
Comment : the icon its file, it has any sizes picture in one file, you can change this one size picture or anoter.